# How should I draw UIBezierPath on CGLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am drawing Circle using `UIBezierPath`. I want to draw it on `CGLayer` so that I can cache circle and draw text on it after some event(by calling `setNeedsDisplay`). How should I draw UIBezierPath on CGContextRef. My code below

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    static CGLayerRef sTextLayer = NULL;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect textBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
    if (sTextLayer == NULL) {
        sTextLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(ctx, textBounds.size, NULL);
        CGContextRef textCtx = CGLayerGetContext(sTextLayer);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor (textCtx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
        UIGraphicsPushContext(textCtx);

        // Draw circle
        UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:textBounds];
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        circle.lineWidth = 2.0;
        [circle fill];

        UIGraphicsPopContext();
    }

    if (self.drawString) {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
        NSString *string = @"HAPPY BIRTHDAY";
        [string drawInRect:textBounds withFont:font];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check sample code and implement this on your project

Answer (score 0):

Get the `CGPath` from the bezier path and then draw using `CGContextAddPath` and `CGContextStrokePath`. You may also want to use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Avoid the use of the `CGLayerRef` altogether and just have `drawRect` draw the `UIBezierPath` with `fill` method (or as Wain suggests, draw the circle using Core Graphics functions).
2. Add a `CAShapeLayer`, setting its `path` to the `CGPathRef` of the `UIBezierPath`, and then add the text as a `CATextLayer` or a `UILabel` subview (in which case, you don't need a `drawRect` implementation at all).

I infer that you're worried about the efficiency of redrawing the circle, but when you render the text, it probably needs to re-render the circle anyway. You could always save a reference to the `UIBezierPath` or do a snapshot, but I'm not sure that's worth it. You can benchmark it and see.